# How to disable SSL verification in robotframework for API testing

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework, urllib3

This is not a question about API testing; *not* selenium web drivers.

Under the hood I believe robot uses pythons urllib3, but we don't get a handle on the http objects to set the context in robotframework so a python solution needs to be a solution for all urllib3 requests.

We have valid ssl certs but the hostname is not a wildcard, and some times hostname has aprefix so verification does not work, either disabling that or disabling ssl validation all together would be good.

```
urllib3.disable_warnings()
```

disables warnings but newer versions fail despite this.